# Jquery Smooth scroll in AngularJS1.0.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

is it possible to do Smooth Scroll with Jquery 1.10.2 in AngularJs 1.0.7? I have tried many examples, but none of them are working. I think I have always the same issue.

According to this example: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

I have:

```
<body ng-cloak>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
<a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
...
<div id="section2">
 ...
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
         }, 500);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

This is not working. I think it´s because Angular is parsing the link. Any ideas? I know there are a couple of directives but not working for me neither. I would like to approach it with Jquery.

Comment: `document.ready` is virtually useless in angular app. Elements don't exist until they get rendered by angular. That's what directives are for...to assure element exists when you run your code

Comment: You mean It should work if I included in a directive, right?

Comment: Yes. You could also delegate the event listener to the `document` using whatever class you want as target but directives are much cleaner

Comment: Your code is actually working for me without any edits. https://plnkr.co/edit/jtNQ8e7qR0eOF69hSzwg?p=preview

Comment: I think it´s related with angular or jquery versions. If I use my versions (AngularJS 1.0.7 and JQuery 1.10.2)  doesn´t work. https://plnkr.co/edit/6kq0pykPWK1FTp30A4wI?p=preview

Comment: I have realized the problem in your example is the jquery version. Nothing related with Angular. The script is not working on JQuery1.10.2